# GLASS - android.widget.RatingBar not allowed to be inflated

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

it looks like I'm not allowed to inflate the RatingBar widget. Is there any similar widget I can use on GLASS? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RemoteViews` class can only inflate a limited subset of widgets in the Android platform, and `RatingBar` is not one of those. The documentation for that class doesn't indicate directly which classes those are, but you can find a list in the [Android app widgets documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

So if you want to use a `RatingBar` in a live card, you have a couple options:

- Create the card using direct rendering and draw the views directly onto the surface, which lets you use any kind of views that you want
- Or, mock up your own rating bar using `ImageView` widgets instead.